# How to create different dropdowns out of one table in Phoenix Elixir

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I am creating an app where I am creating some admin tables so that users can manage their own dropdown lists inside the app.

For instance, one of the dropdowns is the Status of an application Request. I would like to extend this so that I can have a Pickup Location and a Dropoff Location configured from one table with a couple of booleans.

In the part that works, we have defined the table like so:

```
defmodule Id.Admin.Status do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  schema "statuses" do
    field :status, :string

    timestamps()
  end
...
end
```

and the Request schema:

```
defmodule Id.AccessId.Request do
  use Ecto.Schema
  @timestamps_opts [type: :utc_datetime]
  import Ecto.Changeset

  alias Id.AccessId.Client
  alias Id.Admin.Status
  alias Id.Admin.Clinic

  schema "requests" do
    field :applicant_name, :string
    field :begin_date, :date
    field :clinic_date, :date
    field :end_date, :date
    field :file_number, :string
    field :notes, :string

    belongs_to :statuses, Status

    belongs_to :client, Client
    timestamps()
  end
end
```

With in the Request controller we have:

```
def new(conn, %{"client_id" => client_id}) do
    client = AccessId.get_client!(client_id)

    changeset = AccessId.change_request(%Request{})
    all_statuses = Admin.list_statuses_dropdown()

    render(conn, "new.html",
      client: client,
      all_statuses: all_statuses,
      changeset: changeset
    )
  end
```

And creating the dropdown in the Admin Context:

```
def list_statuses_dropdown(tenant) do
  status_query = from s in Status, select: {s.status, s.id}
  Repo.all(status_query)
end
```

That is all working. Now I am wanting to add a Dropoff Location, and a Pickup Location. 90% of the locations are the same, so I was wanting to use one table, like so: and was thinking of adding the Locations to the migration, but don't know:

```
defmodule Id.Admin.Location do
  use Ecto.Schema
  import Ecto.Changeset

  schema "id_types" do
    field :dropoff_location, :boolean, default: false
    field :pickup_location, :boolean, default: false
    field :location_name, :string

    timestamps()
  end
...
end
```

I am thinking thinking that I add lines something like:

```
defmodule Id.Repo.Migrations.CreateRequests do
  use Ecto.Migration

  def change do
    create table(:requests) do
      add(:clinic_date, :date)
      add(:applicant_name, :string)
      add(:file_number, :string)
      add(:begin_date, :date)
      add(:end_date, :date)
      add(:notes, :string)
      add(:client_id, references(:clients, on_delete: :delete_all))
      add(:statuses_id, references(:statuses, on_delete: :nothing))


      
      add(:dropoff_location, references(:locations, on_delete: :nothing))
      add(:pickup_location, references(:locations, on_delete: :nothing)) 



      timestamps()
    end

    create(index(:requests, [:statuses_id]))
    create(index(:requests, [:client_id]))
  end
end
```

But do not know how I can access the new references in the schema. Is it possible to access it somehow to a belongs_to? Or is this a bad idea, and should really just set up two tables.